# Python 3 , Rodeo IDE , Error: Pip is not installed

Tags: pip, python-3.5, rodeo

I installed Rodeo on Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS using the following commands, (as listed at the rodeo website):

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 33D40BC6
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://rodeo-deb.yhat.com/ rodeo main"

#### install rodeo and run it
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y install rodeo
```

I have also installed Python 3 (Python 3.5.2) and Pip3 via

```
 sudo apt-get -y install python3-pip
```

But when I launch Rodeo, the following errors occur in the Rodeo startup:

```
There was an error running python

$python3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/__init__.py", line 
33, in vendored
__import__(vendored_name, globals(), locals(), level=0)
ImportError: No module named 'pip._vendor.pkg_resources'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/Rodeo/resources/app/node/kernels/python/start_kernel.py", 
    line 21, in <module>
    import pip
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 13, in 
      <module>
    from pip.exceptions import InstallationError, CommandError, 
      PipError
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/exceptions.py", line 6, in 
     <module>
     from pip._vendor.six import iteritems
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/__init__.py", line 
     75, in <module>
     vendored("pkg_resources")
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/__init__.py", line 
    36, in vendored
__import__(modulename, globals(), locals(), level=0)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in 
   _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 634, in 
   _load_backward_compatible
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pkg_resources-0.0.0-py2.py3-none- 
     any.whl/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2927, in <module>
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pkg_resources-0.0.0-py2.py3-none- 
    any.whl/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2913, in _call_aside
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pkg_resources-0.0.0-py2.py3-none- 
      any.whl/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2952, in 
  _initialize_master_working_set
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pkg_resources-0.0.0-py2.py3-none- 
     any.whl/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 956, in subscribe
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pkg_resources-0.0.0-py2.py3-none- 
      any.whl/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2952, in <lambda>
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pkg_resources-0.0.0-py2.py3-none- 
    any.whl/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2515, in activate
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pkg_resources-0.0.0-py2.py3-none- 
    any.whl/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2097, in    
      declare_namespace
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pkg_resources-0.0.0-py2.py3-none- 
    any.whl/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2047, in _handle_ns
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pkg_resources-0.0.0-py2.py3-none- 
     any.whl/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2066, in 
 _rebuild_mod_path
  AttributeError: '_NamespacePath' object has no attribute 'sort'

  During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

 Traceback (most recent call last):
    File 
 "/opt/Rodeo/resources/app/node/kernels/python/start_kernel.py", line 
 23, in <module>
     raise Exception('Pip is not installed')
 Exception: Pip is not installed
 Pip is not installed
```

I don't know why these errors occur, since Pip3 is installed and working fine

Answer (score 0):

Try with `pip3 install pip` or `pip install pip`

it should work